# Error Inusual No Se Ejecuta El Código

Tags: android-studio

Tengo un objeto tipo`DatePickerDialog` pero el metodo `void onDataSet()` que esta adentro de este no se ejecuta pero deberia ejecutar el codigo que se encuentra pero no se ejecuta nada.

```
 void DialogoFecha()
{
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    dia = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    mes = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    yearr = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);

      DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(inicio.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {

            dia = dayOfMonth;
            mes = month+1;
            yearr = year;

            cdia = dayOfMonth;
            cmes = month;
            cyear = year;

            //Aqui no sucede nada no se ejecuta
            Toast.makeText(inicio.this, "Debe mostrar algo pero no muestra nada", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

    }
            ,dia,mes,yearr); //???

    //Es la fecha minima que puede aparecer en este caso la fecha actual
    datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis());

    long time = 26297500000L; //Son 10 Meses
    datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis()+(time));

    //Se en el dialogo se apreta el boton cancelar
    datePickerDialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
            Toast.makeText(inicio.this, "Cancelado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    //Si se accepta en el dialogo fecha y abre el dialogo hora

    datePickerDialog.setButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            Toast.makeText(inicio.this, "Acceptado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //Abre el dialogo hora
            DialogoHora();
        }
    });

    //Mostrar el calendario
    datePickerDialog.show();

}
```

Comment: Hola Diego, ¿qué lenguaje estás usando para desarrollar esto? Parece java, en cuyo caso sería ideal que lo pusieras como etiqueta para que la gente experta en ese lenguaje pueda encontrar tu pregunta y ayudarte. Además trata de añadir algo más de información: ¿recibes algún error? ¿cuáles son los pasos que sigues? ¿la función se llama o no? Aparte, la etiqueta de android-studio sólo debería usarse para preguntas sobre el IDE Android Studio y éste no es el caso. Lee [ask] para más información.

Comment: Ups es que antes solo se usaba java pero ahora también  Kotlin, ??? Lo único que hago es compilarlo y ejecutarlo en el emulador de android hasta en dispositivos reales, lo único que sucede es que ahí una parte del código que debería ejecutarse pero no se ejecuta, el método Toast debería mostrar un mensaje en la pantalla pero no muestra nada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Soluciono mi propia pregunta:

Tenemos metodo `void onDataSet()` que se ejecuta cuando el usuario finaliza el dialogo pero agregue otro metodo que tambien se ejecuta cuando el usuario finaliza el dialogo y esto generaba un conflicto

este método remplazaba el metodo `void onDataSet()` simplemente ahi que eliminar este metodo porque estaba de manera extra:

**Lo unico que ahi que hacer es borrar este metodo:**

`datePickerDialog.setButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()`